# What's a good *portable* WAMP?

Tags: web-development, portable, wamp

I generally hand install Apache, PHP & MySql, and its a PITA every time.

Now I have a fresh Windows install and want to get some development finished quickly, and don't have the luxury of time to figure out the install & config again.

I will use a WAMP, and maybe install my own PHP + Apache + MySql later. otoh, if the WAMP is good, I might as well just stick with it.

The reinstall is convincing me to use portable apps wherever possible, so that I can transfer them, with settings, between PCs, or just wipe C: (all of my programs are on E:), fresh install Windows & pick up where I left off.

So, what's a good, ***portable*** WAMP? It would be a bonus if it's easy to change PHP versions.

[Clarification] By portable, I only mean  that it doesn't write to the registry, so that, after reinstalling WIndows, it will still run.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "portable"? Does it have to run from e.g. USB stick or just work on different Windowses? Did you consider Docker?

Comment: By portable, I only mean  that it doesn't write to the registry, so that, after reinstalling WIndows, it will still run. Of course, that does also mean that I ***could*** put it on USB stick and run it on a different PC. I don't use Docker, although I am aware of it. If these is an off the shelf Docker solution, I will consider it, but I can't put in any work or learning on it, as I just don't have the time.

Comment: Update: I am using Laragon, which seems excellent, although I cannot currently get Xdebug working.